# No se aplica animación CSS a Span mediante JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

He estado intentado saber el por qué no me toma la animación, si la clase se aplica completamente, a excepción de la animación. Este es el código:
CSS

```
.wrong{
    color: gray;
}

.animate-wrong{
    animation: animate 1s ease;
    background-color: orange;
}

@keyframes animate{
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
else {
            wrongSpan = quote.children[idx]
            wrongSpan.className = 'wrong'
            // wrongSpan.className = 'animate-wrong'
            // ya intenté con con la clase específica,
            // con las 2 clases juntas, con add, remove, etc.
            // por eso finalmente intenté con style.animation
            wrongSpan.style.animation = 'animate 1s ease';
            console.log(wrongSpan)
            quoteComplete.pop()
        }
```

Intenté con la animación en la misma clase, con setTimeout y requestAnimationFrame.Si alguien sabe algo, agradecería la ayuda! :)

[image: inspector de elementos]

Ya intenté de todo jajaj, le apliqué el estilo a otro elemento y si funciona, la animación también debería estar en este caso en la letra "u"
[image: Gif animacion]

Comment: Así como has puesto tu código no se va a animar nada nunca, porque agregas la clases `wrong` cuando la que tiene la animación es `animate-wrong`

Comment: Le estoy agregando la animación directamente desde wrongSpan.style.animation, aunque también intenté agregando la animación a la clase wrong. El código finalmente terminó como está, después de intentar varias posibilidades, como explico en el post.

Comment: Cuál de los dos quieres usar? CSS o Javascript? Simplemente con CSS ya estaría funcionando bien referenciado el nombre correcto

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz pasa que es tipo un jueguito, dónde si el usuario se equivoca, se le aplica esa clase y esa animación. El resto del código funciona bien, sólo es la parte de la animación y no se toca en ninguna otra línea, por eso no pongo más contexto.

-- Incluso detecta el background-color de .animate-wrong

Answer (score 1):

En el CSS primeramente se debe referenciar el nombre de la animación: **animate**

```
.animate-wrong {
  animation: animate 1s ease
}

@keyframes animate {

}
```

También se puede usar independientemente:

```
.animate-wrong {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animate
}
```

Y otra cosa importante, no olvides usar la compatibilidad para otros navegadores. En los dos `@keiframes` debe estar la misma configuración:

```
@keyframes animate {

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {

}
```

**Actualizado:**

> me acabo de dar cuenta de que no toma ninguna opción de transform, ni
> sus respectivos sin la propiedad transform, es decir: transform:
> rotate(30deg);

La función de animación sobre un elemento `inline` no funciona. La etiqueta `span` es un elemento `inline` por defecto.

**La solución es darle al `span` un `display: inline-block`**

Te muestro dos ejemplos con evento click y scroll (porque no sé tu evento), para que puedas tomar como referencia de usar Javascript junto con CSS.

De esta forma, toda la animación está en CSS, y que el evento en el script solo invoca al los estilos en CSS

Éste ejemplo es con evento click que usa los estilos en CSS:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span");

span.classList.add("wrong");

function uno() {
    span.classList.toggle("animate-wrong");
};

span.addEventListener("click", uno);
```

```css
span {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size: 30px
}

.wrong {
color: gray;
background-color: lightgreen
}

.animate-wrong {
  background-color: orange;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animate
}

@keyframes animate {
  
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
}
to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
}
to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
}
}
```

```html
<body>

    <span>Hello Word!</span>

</body>
```

Éste otro ejemplo sería con el evento scroll, de la siguiente manera:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span");
let scroll = 0;
span.classList.add("wrong");

function dos(e) {
    
if (scroll > 5) {
    
span.classList.add("animate-wrong");

} else if (scroll < 5) {
                            
span.classList.remove("animate-wrong");
                            
}

scroll = this.scrollY;
                            
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", dos);
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px
} span {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px
}

.wrong {
color: gray;
  background-color: lightgreen
}

.animate-wrong {
  background-color: orange;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animate
} 

@keyframes animate {
  
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
}
to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
}
to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
}

}
```

```html
<body>

    <span>Hello Word!</span>

</body>
```

Comment: Da igual, tengo la animación así:
wrongSpan.style.animation = 'animate 1s ease';
 De igual manera cree una clase .animation-wrong con la animación y la implementé anteriormente en el js como haces tu, sin embargo, tampoco funciona. Recuerda que es sólo la animación, la clase se aplica correctamente.

Comment: @NulleWFN Te fijaste inspeccionando el elemento si la animación se encuentra en sus estilos? también suele haber un desplegable que muestra las propiedades de la animación. Tienes otra animación anterior sobre el mismo elemento que puede estar interfiriendo? te lo pregunto porque me funciona bien a mi.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ no sé como poner fotos ajajj así que te describo lo del inspector una vez seleccionado el elemento al que se le añade la clase:
.wrong {
  color: gray;
  animation: animate 1s ease;
} animation sale tachado en el inspector, sin más detalles. Y no, no tengo ninguna otra animación en todo el proyecto, probé creando un div en html y especificando la clase y sí tomaba la animación. Debe ser algo de javascript, pero no sé por qué no toma la animación.

Comment: @NulleWFN eso suele indicar que la propiedad animation tiene un valor incorrecto, por cierto no se si reasignar la propiedad 'className' entera sea buena idea, esa propiedad contiene un string con todas las clases del elemento, si la reasignas podrías estar borrando clases anteriores que necesitas. Mejor usa classList y sus propiedades add, remove, replace, contains y toggle.

Comment: @NulleWFN puedes agregar fácilmente una imagen guardada en tu equipo, editando la pregunta y usando la herramienta para adjuntar imágenes.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ añadí una foto, aunque ya no aparece la propiedad tachada. será por el span que no anima?

Comment: Sugiero que suspenda cualquier otra acción dentro de tu función, que no tengan nada que ver con la animación, y así hasta que encuentres cual es el problema

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz me acabo de dar cuenta de que no toma ninguna opción de transform, ni sus respectivos sin la propiedad transform, es decir:
transform: rotate(30deg);
rotate = 30deg;
pero todas las otras propiedades si las toma en cuenta, font size, background-color en animación y clase. funciona la animación con un cambio de background-color, SÓLO el transform.

Comment: @NulleWFN, si aún no solucionaste, aquí ya está la solución. Cuando mencionaste que solamente el `transform` no funcionaba, inmediatamente me di cuenta de que la etiqueta `span` es `inline` por defecto, lo cual no funcionaría nunca. Entonces edite mi respuesta con la simple solución de darle al `span` un `display: inline-block`

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Eso era, hermanoooo! Se solucionó altoque. Gracias compa! :)

Comment: Ok. No olvides marcar ésta respuesta con **✓** para cerrar tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve de ayuda, puedes cancelar y volver a iniciar todas las animaciones asociadas a un elemento. De paso puedes ver si tiene la animación que agregaste con la clase. Tambien puedes cancelar, pausar, reproducir programáticamente una o mas de una animaciones que estén asociadas al elemento.

```
  box.getAnimations().forEach((anim) => {
    console.log(anim) // <- deberias ver por consola las animaciones del elemento
    anim.cancel()
    anim.play()
  })
```

[getAnimations()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) devuelve un arreglo de animaciones, y proporciona métodos para todas las acciones que te dije anteriormente. Esto es por si te da una solución provisoria al menos pero no debería ser necesario usar esta API. Si no, no tengo idea de lo que ocurre.